# Using residue theorem to compute

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I am studying previous exam questions from complex analysis, and at the same time I am trying to learn about the Residue theorem.

Now I stumbled upon the integral

\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+is)^2}dx
\end{aligned}

And I was wondering if it is possible to use the residue theorem on this particular integral. It seems like there are two strategies to use the Residue theorem

\begin{aligned}
\int_{C} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \sum^{k}_{i = 1}  \operatorname{res}(f,a_{i})
\end{aligned}
First one is to find $ \operatorname{res}(f,a_{i})$ by finding the poles and then taking the limits and the second method seems to be series expand, and I suppose I am in the second case here? However I am not exactly sure how to evaluate it.

Comment: Where are you expecting to find poles?

Comment: What is $s$?  It appears in the integral.

Comment: If $s$ is just a constant, then I guess this is just a standard Gaussian integral, $\sqrt{2\pi}$ because the measure is translation invariant.

Comment: @Brightsunbr I would assume that  $is $ is pure imaginary.

Comment: @Brightsun Yes, the integral is independent of $s$. But that's not just translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure! The map $x\mapsto x+is$ is not a translation on the line. (You can easily use Cauchy's Theorem to show the integral is independent of $s$.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What I had in mind is that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+c)^2/2}d(x+c)$ for any constant $c$ (even complex). The right way to see it is by means of Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: So the one that says if $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected domain $D$ and if $C$ is a simple connected contour lies inside $D$ and $C$ is a triangular contour then $\int_{c} f(z) dz = 0$?

Comment: @Chengdu It's an application of $\int_C f=0$ if  $f(z)=e^{-z^2/2}$ and $C$ is  a _rectangular_ path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, it's hard to see how we can use RT here, since $e^{-z^2/2}$ is entire; there are no poles, hence no residues.

*If* this came up on a complex exam, *maybe* this is what they had in mind: Say the integral is $I(s)$. It's an **exercise** to use Cauchy's Theorem to show that $I(s)=I(0)$; now if we're allowed to regard $I(0)=\sqrt{2\pi}$ as "well-known" we're done.

**Comment** It's actually an important integral: If you write $(x+is)^2=x^2+isx-s^2$ you see that $I(s)=\sqrt{2\pi}$ implies that the function $e^{-x^2/2}$ is its own Fourier transform.

Ok, for the benefit of readers who don't want  to do any exercises:

**Details:** Let $f(z)=e^{-z^2/2}$ and define $$I(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+is)\,dx.$$

> > $I(s)=I(0)$ for every $s\in\Bbb C$.

Proof: It's clear that $I(s+it)=I(s)$ for $t\in\Bbb R$, so we may assume that $s\in\Bbb R$. In fact we'll assume $s>0$ just so it's clear what the picture looks like.

For $A>0$ let $$I_A(s)=\int_{-A}^Af(x+is)\,dx,$$so $I(s)=\lim_{A\to\infty}I_A(s)$.

Let $R_A$ be the rectangle with vertices $\pm A$, $\pm A+is$. Since $f$ is entire, Cauchy's Theorem shows that $$\int_{R_A}f=0.$$Parametrizing $R_A$ in the obvious way, and letting $[p,q]$ denote the line segment from $p$ to $q$, this says precisely that $$I_A(0)-I_A(s)=\int_{[-A,-A+is]}f - \int_{[A, A+is]}f.$$Now since $|e^{\alpha+i\beta}|=e^\alpha$we see that $$|f(x+iy)|=e^{(y^2-x^2)/2},$$hence $$|f(z)|\le e^{(s^2-A^2)/2}
\quad(z\in[A,A+is]).$$So $$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{[A,A+is]}f=0$$by uniform convergence. Similarly for $[-A,-A+is]$; hence $$\lim_{A\to\infty}(I_A(0)-I_A(s))=0,$$or $$I(0)-I(s)=0.$$

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure what you mean by $I(s) = I(0)$ and using Cauchy's theorem is normally used to show that the integral equals zero, but I don't think that is the case here?

Comment: @Chengdu Ok, I added some details. You should **note** that this would be a straightforward exercise in our _undergraduate_ complex class - I mention this to suggest you may want to do some studying and some elementary exercises before starting on those exams...

Comment: Thank you, yes I am well aware however my teacher haven't given us any exercises or any examples of the applications of this theorem so I am happy to see it here thank you